# Deploying Ruby on rails on Deamhost fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, bundler, dreamhost

I'm trying to deploy a simple Ruby on Rails app to dreamhost but I'm getting an error related to the bundle command. Here is the error:

```
    servers: ["bullseye.dreamhost.com"]
    [bullseye.dreamhost.com] executing command
    command finished
  * executing "find /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/releases/20110123014150/public/images /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/releases/20110123014150/public/stylesheets /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/releases/20110123014150/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201101230141.52 {} ';'; true"
    servers: ["bullseye.dreamhost.com"]
    [bullseye.dreamhost.com] executing command
    command finished
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "ls -xt /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/releases"
    servers: ["bullseye.dreamhost.com"]
    [bullseye.dreamhost.com] executing command
    command finished
  * executing "bundle install --gemfile /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/releases/20110123014150/Gemfile --path /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["bullseye.dreamhost.com"]
    [bullseye.dreamhost.com] executing command
*** [err :: bullseye.dreamhost.com] sh: bundle: command not found
    command finished
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/releases/20110123014150; true"
    servers: ["bullseye.dreamhost.com"]
    [bullseye.dreamhost.com] executing command
    command finished
failed: "sh -c 'bundle install --gemfile /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/releases/20110123014150/Gemfile --path /home/USER-NAME/MY-DOMAIN/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on bullseye.dreamhost.com
```

Here is my deploy.rb file.

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :user, "MY-USERNAME"
set :password, "MY-PASSWORD"
set :domain, 'bullseye.dreamhost.com'  # Dreamhost servername where your account is located 
set :project, 'blog'  # Your application as its called in the repository
set :application, 'MY-DOMAIN'  # Your app's location (domain or sub-domain name as setup in panel)
set :applicationdir, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"  # The standard Dreamhost setup

# version control config
set :scm_username, 'MY-SVN-USERNAME'
set :scm_password, 'MY-SVN-PWD'
set :repository, "http://MY-SVN-URL/01/blog/"

# roles (servers)
role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true

# deploy config
set :deploy_to, applicationdir
set :deploy_via, :export

# additional settings
default_run_options[:pty] = false  # Forgo errors when deploying from windows

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

I found a similar question at [Bundle install failing when deploying a Rails 3 app to Dreamhost with Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656591/bundle-install-failing-when-deploying-a-rails-3-app-to-dreamhost-with-capistrano) but the solution didn't work. Anybody have any ideas as to what might be happening in my case?

Comment: Perhaps 'bundler' isn't in the PATH you get when you're running these commands? As a first start, does `which bundler` return anything when you just ssh in? If `bundler` is in your PATH in an interactive login shell, perhaps you need to move the commands to set the PATH to a different bash startup file, as described in the `INVOCATION` section of the `bash(1)` manpage. (It's a beast of a section, but try `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`.)

Comment: @sarnold, thanks for the hints but I couldn't get that to work. But I did figure it out otherwise, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this figured out eventually. What I did was

- ssh into the dreamhost server and execute `which bundle` command
- from ssh session execute echo $PATH command
- edit config/deploy.rb and combine both strings with a `:` between and place inside `default_environment` PATH value, see below

  set :default_environment, {
    'PATH' => "'/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin//bundle:/home/sayed3/.gems/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games'"
  }

Once I did this it was able to execute the bundle command successfully, but then I started running into some other issues. I eventually decided to use a VPS that I have hosted elsewhere, but I'm sure if I spent a bit more time I could have figured it out.

Comment: `default_environment["PATH"] = "$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/"` was what I added

Answer (score 1):

Besides adding the path to bundle, as specified above, I also had to add the following line to my *config/deploy.rb* in order to force capistrano to use **bash**, instead of the default shell, which, on dreamhost, is dash:

```
set :shell, '/bin/bash'
```