# "Gem bundler is not installed" in Capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, bundler

Here is the error caused by rake in Capistrano deployment. The error also causes the rollback and failure of the rails 3.1.3 deployment (with rvm installed for single user).

```
 ** [out :: 76.195.225.93] ←[31mERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem in
    command finished in 54ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/byop/releases/20120302230229; true"
```

`gem list` shows bundler 1.0.22 installed. What could cause the error? Is it because of the rvm? Thanks so much.

Comment: this error looks like from `.rvmrc` file, are you sure the ruby specified there is installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error disappeared after adding the following in deploy.rb and deployed successfully:

```
   task :gems, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do 
     run "cd #{current_path}; #{shared_path}/bin/bundle unlock" 
     run "cd #{current_path}; nice -19 #{shared_path}/bin/bundle install vendor/" # nice -19 is very important otherwise DH will kill the process! 
     run "cd #{current_path}; #{shared_path}/bin/bundle lock" 
   end
```

More reading here: [Bundle install failing when deploying a Rails 3 app to Dreamhost with Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656591/bundle-install-failing-when-deploying-a-rails-3-app-to-dreamhost-with-capistran)